# wcout can't print wstring from wcin in Windows

Tags: c++

`wcout` can't print `wstring` from `wcin` in Windows. But in Linux(WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04), it works fine.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
using namespace std;

int main(int argv, char** argc) 
{
    locale mylocale("");
    locale::global(mylocale);

    wcout.imbue(mylocale);
    wcin.imbue(mylocale);
    
    wstring name;

    wcout << L"너의 이름은?";
    getline(wcin, name);

    wcout << name << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Following is my expected output.

```
너의 이름은?김철수
김철수
```

But, `000` is printed.

```
너의 이름은?김철수
000
```

OR just blank

```
너의 이름은?김철수
```

sometimes 'P', '@'...

Console `Active code page: 65001` checked.

`wcin` puts wstring in `name` properly.
`name.size()` shows the number of literal that i typed.

It's okay with get input from a file.

I use [D2coding](https://github.com/naver/d2codingfont) font.

Comment: Windows is weird - your console has to have code page 65001 but it also has to use a font that contains the characters you want to display.  What font is the console configured to use?  And if you use the character map does it contain those characters?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I use D2coding font. https://github.com/naver/d2codingfont.

Comment: So, if it is ok when you read the input from a file and print the result to the console then the printing works fine and it is the reading that doesn't work, right?

Comment: Yes. Reading from console (Windows Terminal Powershell) doesn't work. Hardcoded L"" like wstring also print out fine. And Reading the input from a file only works in Cmd. And English input works.

Comment: Maybe setting the code page with chcp only changes the output code page and doesn't change the input code page.  the Windows API has both SetConsoleCP and SetConsoleOutputCP so maybe you are better to call them inside your program.

Comment: This looks really helpful: https://alfps.wordpress.com/2011/11/22/unicode-part-1-windows-console-io-approaches/  Here is where it talks about why input doesn't work: https://alfps.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/unicode-part-2-utf-8-stream-mode/#utf8_mode_input and then it explains how to fix it.